# Where to see the logged sql statements in play2?

Tags: sql, logging, playframework-2.0, anorm

I found there is such a configuration in `application.conf`:

```
# If enabled, log SQL statements being executed.
db.default.logStatements=true
```

I've enabled it, but I can't find any log file which logged executed sqls.

Where can I find it, or do I miss something?

Comment: Play and Scala are **extremely** version sensitive -- adding version numbers to all questions will help newcomers to the play/scala world form tripping over version specific advise that won't (ever) work for them.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### 1. application.conf

make sure:

```
db.default.logStatements=true
```

This config is actually a setting of bonecp which is connection pool used in play2

### 2. custom logger

Add a custom logger configuration to `conf/logger.xml`.

The content may be:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="play" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

The `com.jlbox.bonecp` is for `bonecp`, and `play` and `application` are for play2.

### 3. disable logger settings in application.conf

Comment the logger settings in `application.conf`:

```
# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:
# logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
# logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
# logger.application=DEBUG
```

Restart play, and you will see all executed SQLs(including parameter values).

Comment: Works perfect in play 2.3.4

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 2.4.2.  They pulled anorm out of the core dist so I'm guessing something else is going on.

Comment: `db.default.logSql=true` appears to be working in play 2.5.3

Answer (score 6):

This no longer works in Play 2.4.2 from what I can tell.  The default connection pool engine was changed over to HikariCP.

Add this to your application.conf and follow the directions below.  Things should work:

**Application.conf**

```
db.default.pool = "bonecp"
db.default.bonecp.logStatements=true
```

**conf/logger.xml**
Add a custom logger configuration to conf/logger.xml.

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="play" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Comment: This changes the pool back to BoneCP. Is there a way to get logging with HikariCP? (I am using Play 2.4.3)

Comment: @PatrikBeck: I tried similar approach with HikariCP's package, `<logger name="com.zaxxer" level="DEBUG"/>` and I do get `c.z.h.p.HikariPool` debug messages but not the actual SQL statements. Maybe HikariCP just doesn't support this. :-/ See also [related Play 2.4 question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30647074/56285).

Comment: For now, I'm simply doing this: use BoneCP (with above settings) while debugging some Anorm/SQL issue, and switch back to default while done.

Comment: I was able to enable logging while keeping Hikary, using log4jdbc . It wraps the JDBC driver and logs the SQL statements.

Comment: @PatrikBeck: How exactly, can you post an answer about that? Did you need to modify repository code as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30654324/56285?

Comment: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JDBC-Logging#using-log4jdbc-log4j2

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following to application.conf (works for me in play 2.2.1)

```
db.default.logStatements=true

logger.com.jolbox.bonecp=DEBUG
```

Comment: This does not appear to work under play 2.3 with scala, whereas the solution @Freewind gave does.

Answer (score 1):

For HikariCP (i.e. starting with Play 2.4), see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JDBC-Logging:

> HikariCP does not inherently include JDBC logging at this time. This is a conscious decision, not an oversight or undeveloped future roadmap item. Nearly all major database have a JDBC driver capable of logging on its own. For those that do not, log4jdbc-log4j2 is a good option.
>
> This wiki page documents how to enable logging for common databases, as well as log4jdbc-log4j2.

For log4jdbc-log4j2: add `"org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2" % "log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1" % "1.16"` to `libraryDependencies`; configuration is described at https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/.