# Play framework - Mysql error on save model

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, playframework, timestamp

I have a Model created as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="news_items")
public class NewsItem extends Model {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public long id;
public String url;
public long friend_id;
public int count_for_the_day;
public String friend_name;
public String friend_img;
public Date friend_posted_at;
public String friend_text;

@Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
public Date current_time = new Date();

}
```

I am trying to save it in controller in the following way:

```
                     NewsItem _newsItem = new NewsItem();


                          _newsItem.url = shared_url;
                          _newsItem.friend_name = status.getUser().getName();
                          _newsItem.friend_img = status.getUser().getProfileImageURL();
                          _newsItem.friend_id = status.getUser().getId();
                          _newsItem.friend_text = status.getText();
                          _newsItem.friend_posted_at = status.getCreatedAt();
                          _newsItem.count_for_the_day = 1;
                          _newsItem.save();
                          resultItems.add(_newsItem);
```

None of the values are `null`. I am getting an error in the activator console as:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] 
error[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_time) values 
('http://www.lahamag.com/Details/42019/119/%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%' at line 1]
```

The partial table structure relevant to the variable in mysql DB looks like this:

```
| friend_text       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| current_time      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have following questions:

1. I am not executing any query. I suppose Play internally does that. How I can see full query with values of what is being executed when it does `save()`?
2. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can see full query with values of what is being executed?

1. In **application.conf** add

   `db.default.logStatements=true`
2. Create a file **logger.xml** inside **conf** folder with content

   ```
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <encoder>
           <pattern>%-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
       </encoder>
   </appender>

   <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="DEBUG">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="play" level="DEBUG">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="application" level="DEBUG">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   </logger>
   ```

   This will show the sql generated in console.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371907/where-to-see-the-logged-sql-statements-in-play2)

> How to solve this?

The error is because [**current_time**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is reserved word in mysql.

Solution

```
@Column(name="`current_time`")   //backticks
public Date current_time = new Date();
```

It will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `current_time` is reserved word in MySQL and should be quoted, TBH I have no idea how to force these quotes in Ebean, so fastest solution is renaming the field to some non-reserved like `publishDate`.

BTW, as you can see you can use **camelCase** names for your fields in models, Ebean handles them correctly by changing in queries to **underscored_version**