# How do you print out filled in Anorm SQL statements in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm, playframework-2.4

How can I print out the SQL state that is going to be run using Anorm.

Example

```
SQL(s"SELECT $terms FROM $PERSON_TABLE WHERE name = {name}").on("name" -> "Bill")
```

Printing that gives me this

```
SimpleSql(anorm.SqlQuery$$anon$1@1197b8ab,Map(name -> ParameterValue(Bill)),<function1>,false)
```

I want to see the exact query that is going to run on the server,

```
SELECT id, name, state FROM person WHERE name = "Bill";
```

I dont want to use interpolation like this

```
s"SELECT $terms FROM $PERSON_TABLE WHERE name = $name"
```

I need to be able to see all the escaped characters and what is wrapped in (') and what is wrapped in (")

Using:

Play 2.4.1-Scala

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: First you should not use string interpolation with SQL statement, but Anorm interpolation `SQL"SELECT #$terms FROM #$table WHERE name = $name"` which handle parameters with a simple `$` and plain concat with `#$` (see Anorm doc). Then Anorm 2.5.0 is out.

Comment: @cchantep What is wrong with using string interpolation?  I understand not using it for things coming from the user to prevent injections but is it wrong to use when the parts that are being interpolated are things I provide in code.

Comment: Why using the standard interpolation which *can* work with some prepared statement, whereas the Anorm one will always work?

Comment: Prior to 2.4 it was by configuring a [logger for bonecp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371907/where-to-see-the-logged-sql-statements-in-play2), but bonecp has been replaced. I haven't used the new method yet, but there is a clue [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647074/how-to-enable-trace-debugging-output-with-anorm-on-play-2-4-0).

Comment: Check also the response here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371907/where-to-see-the-logged-sql-statements-in-play2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [debuging utility](http://acolyte.eu.org/scala.html#Debug_utility) from Acolyte (my framework).

```scala
import acolyte.jdbc.AcolyteDSL

AcolyteDSL.debuging() { implicit con =>
  // debug any JDBC execution within

  SQL"SELECT * FROM Test WHERE id = $id"
  // Will print the stmt prepared for
}
```

Comment: Any way to have it print the filled in statement?  It prints it out with ?, ? and then lists them after with value and type.  And thanks for letting me know about 2.5.0.  Upgrading to that fixed one of my issues where the query was being interpolated then the order mixed up.  I'm still accepting as it solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Acolyte print the list or parameters. For each `?` just consider the parameter detail (name + type) indicated at the corresponding position.

Answer (score 0):

sql.getFilledStatement(connection, true) in the standard anorm API seems to be working quite well

Comment: "getFilledStatement" does not appear to exist anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using prepared statement:

```scala
val yourStmt = SQL(s"SELECT $terms FROM $PERSON_TABLE WHERE name = {name}").on("name" -> "Bill")
val pstmt = yourStmt.preparedStatement(con)
pstmt.foreach(p => println(p))
```

(worked for me in anorm 2.5.0 using interpolated strings)

Comment: Using string interpolation `SQL(s"..")` rather than Anorm interpolation `SQL".."` introduces SQL injection risk.

Comment: This does not work. "preparedStatement" expects more parameters than simply connection. I don't understand what I'm supposed to put into the extra parameters because the entire method appears to be undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same question and the answer was **enabling logging for the SQL statements** by adding this configuration in `conf/application.conf`:

```
db.default.logSql=true
```

##### Reference

- tested on [Play Framework v2.6.17](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDatabase#How-to-configure-SQL-log-statement) on PostgreSQL
- it seems to be [the same for v2.8.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#How-to-configure-SQL-log-statement) (the latest as of Jan-2022);
- for older versions, check  [Where to see the logged sql statements in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371907/where-to-see-the-logged-sql-statements-in-play2)