# AWS RDS MySQL performance drop after random timespan

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, netty, amazon-rds

***QUESTION OUTLINE***
Our AWS RDS instance starts slowing down after about 7-14 days, by a quite large factor (~400% load times for a specific set of queries). RDS monitoring shows no signs of resource shortage. (see below the question update for detailed problem description)

---

### **Question Update**

So after more than one month of investigating and some developer support by AWS, I am not exactly closer to a solution.

Here are a couple of steps which I checked off the list, more or less without any further hint of the problem:

- Index / Fragmentation (all tables have correct indexes/keys and have no fragmentation)
- MySQL Stats Update (manually updating stats [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051510/how-can-i-rebuild-indexes-and-update-stats-in-mysql-innodb))
- Thread Concurrency (changing innodb_thread_concurrency to various different parameters)
- Query Cache Hit Ratio doesn't show problems
- EXPLAIN to see if any SELECTs are actually slow or not using indexes/keys
- SLOW QUERY LOG (returns no results, because see paragraph below, it's a number of prepared SELECTs)
- RDS and EC2 are within one VPC

For explanation, the used PlayFramework (2.3.8) has BoneCP and we are using eBeans to select our data. So basically I am running through a nested object and all those child objects, this produces a couple of hundred prepared SELECTs for the API call in question. This should basically also be fine for the used hardware, neither CPU nor RAM are extensively used by these operations.

I also included NewRelic for more insights on this issue and did some JVM profiling. Obviously, most of the time is consumed by NETTY/eBeans?
[image: NewRelic JVM Profiling Output]

[image: NewRelic most time consuming operations]

[image: NewRelic most time consuming operations]

Is anyone able to make sense of this?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION: Problem Outline**

Our AWS RDS instance starts slowing down after about 7-14 days, by a quite large factor (~400% load times for a specific set of queries). RDS monitoring shows no signs of resource shortage.

**Infrastructure**

We run a PlayFramework backend for a mobile app on AWS EC2 instances, connected to AWS RDS MySQL instances, one PROD environment, one DEV environment. Usually the PROD EC2 instance is pointing to the PROD RDS instance, and the DEV EC2 points to the DEV RDS (hi from captain obvious!); however sometimes we also let the DEV EC2 point to the PROD DB for some testing purposes. The PlayFramework in use is working with BoneCP.

**Detailed Problem Description**

In a quite essential sync process, our app is making a certain API call many times a day per user. I discussed the backgrounds of the functionality in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513725/playframework-poor-json-deserializing-performance), where, thanks to comments, I could nail the problem down to be a MySQL issue of some kind.

In short, the API call is loading a set of data, the maximum is about 1MB of json data, which currently takes about 18s to load. When things are running perfectly fine, this takes about 4s to load.

Curious enough, what "solved" the problem last time was upgrading the RDS instance to another instance type (from db.m3.large to db.m4.large, which is just a very marginal step). Now, after about 2-3 weeks, the RDS instance is once again performing slow as before. Rebooting the RDS instance showed no effect. Also re-launching the EC2 instance shows no effect.

I also checked if the indices of the affected mySQL tables are set properly, which is the case. The API call itself is not eager-loading any BLOB fields or similar, I double-checked this. The CPU-usage of the RDS instances is below 1% most of the time, when I stress tested it with 100 simultaneous API calls, it went to ~5%, so this is not the bottleneck. Memory is fine too, so I guess the RDS instance doesn't start swapping which could slow down the whole process.

Giving hard evidence, a (smaller) public API call on the DEV environment currently takes 2.30s load, on the PROD environment it takes 4.86s. Which is interesting, because the DEV environment has both in EC2 and RDS a much smaller instance type. So basically the turtle wins the race here. (If you are interested in this API call I am happy to share it with you via PN, but I don't really want to post links to API calls, even if they are basically public.)

**Conclusion**

Concluding, it feels (I wittingly say 'feels') like the DB is clogged after x days of usage / after a certain amount of API calls. Not sure if this a RDS-specific issue, once I 'largely' reset the DB instance by changing the instance type, things run fast and smooth. But re-creating my DB instance from a snapshot every 2 weeks is not an option, especially if I don't understand why this is happening.

Do you have any ideas what further steps I could take to investigate this matter?

Comment: API call to load only 1MB of data should be much quicker that what you're experiencing. Your question doesn't show any factual conclusion that it's MySQL's fault, which means that you might be looking at the symptom and not the cause. Did you measure `I/O` of your RDS instance? What is your dataset size and what is your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value? You will rarely get CPU bottleneck with MySQL, it's usually the I/O subsystem that clogs the performance.

Comment: Well, the data is distributed over some tables and joined, so with 1 api call there are lots of prepared statements fired. So the calculation does take some time. The factual conclusion is stated in the earlier asked SO question, where I at first wrongly concluded, that the JSON (de)serialization is the culprit. And it's undermined by the experiment, that if I switch the very same code from the PROD RDS instance to the DEV RDS instance, the time consumed decreases (though PROD has more resources). (Going to next comment, running out of characters .. ;))

Comment: I did not yet measure I/O of the RDS instance, but why would this decrease after some time? Especially, the PROD environment has stronger specs than the DEV environment. The dataset size of the db in question is about 800MB, the innodb_buffer_pool_size is set by RDS to 75% of available RAM (in my case this is 6123683840). I fully agree on the CPU not being the bottleneck.

Comment: I can tell you what I'm guessing, but it's better to determine accurately than believe some random guy's guesses :) it might be the case where you're creating too many file descriptors. However, I've never seen it affect MySQL to extent you're having. Have you tried using MySQL's slow query log feature to determine which queries are slow? Do you know how many queries you're dealing with per second and how much your server can deliver? Do you use `innodb_file_per_table`, and if yes - how many tables are there? Do you use persistent db connections?

Comment: Yes, I tried to minimize the guess-work, but now I am stuck. I thought about the slow query log, but as said, the API call rather fires a couple of hundred prepared statements in short time than one large/slow query. I tried tweaking and changing this from within the PlayFramework, without luck, this brought no change. How many queries/s would be interesting, I will look into that. Rergarding innodb_file_per_table - 1 (as defaulted by AWS). Persistent DB connection is a yes, the PlayFramework uses BoneCP, which is obviously not perfect, but should be good enough. Thanks so far!

Comment: If I were you, I'd try with slow log. If talking to MySQL took so much time, then slow query log will tell you what it is. It might be the bulk of those few hundred queries, it might be one of them - point being, that log will tell you exactly what went on. Are you preparing and executing the prepared statements within transaction or not? This is very important because that dictates how MySQL will spend its I/O. I've a hunch you're I/O bound, if it turns out MySQL is the problem. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` can also tell you which part of query is slow - seeking, parsing or sending via network.

Comment: Activated the slow log, as feared, it doesn't return anything. The statements are (as seen in the linked question) managed by JPA / eBeans / playFramework, I can't really tune anything there, and I believe this stuff is basically optimized. But I will try and analyze the set of queries with your proposed EXPLAIN EXTENDED, maybe I can find something.

Comment: AWS recently introduced a pretty new thing, an X-Ray, which they claim to be an advanced integrated cross-app, cross-service tracer. It's not at full service yet, but they give away the access to preview now. Have you tried that already, in order to pinpoint the exact location of the failure?

Answer (score 4):

(Too long for just a comment)  I know you have checked a lot of things, but I would like to look at them with a different set of eyes...

Please provide

```
SHOW VARIABLES;  (probably need post.it or something, due to size)
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
how much RAM?  Sounds like 7.5G
The query.  -- Unclear what query/queries you are using
SHOW CREATE TABLE  for the table(s) in the query -- indexes, datatypes, etc
```

(Some of the above may help with "clogging over time" question.)

Meanwhile, here are some guesses/questions/etc...

- Some other customer sharing the hardware is busy.
- It could be a network problem?
- Shrink `long_query_time` to 1 so you can catch slow queries.
- When are backups done on your instance?
- 4s-18s to load a megabyte -- what percentage of that is SQL statements?
- Do you "batch" the inserts?  Is it a single transaction?  Are lengthy queries going on at the same time?
- What, if any, MySQL tunables did you change from the AWS defaults?
- 6GB buffer_pool on a 7.5GB partition?  That sounds dangerously tight.  Can you see if there was any swapping?
- Any `PARTITIONing` involved?  (Of course the `CREATE` will answer that.)

Comment: Thanks! ad show variables/global status: are there any specific values which I should look at? (https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mmg-standard/assets/misc/global_status.txt and https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mmg-standard/assets/misc/variables.txt for the output in .txt). RAM is 8GB. The query comes from eBean (I am selecting a set of nested objects), there is some room for improvement - but basically it works as it should. Indexes/keys are fine. To your other points: no other customer uses the hardware ... (cont. next comment)

Comment: ... network SHOULD be fine (got this reassured by the AWS support team). long_query doesn't help me here (lots of short SELECTs rather than 1 slow query). Backups are done once a week (RDS default). the Percentage for SQL is about <10%, main time is Java (Eban and scala processes, as seen in one screenshot of NewRelic). Batch inserts - no, but the main problem are SELECTs here. Tunables - just minor tweaks for inno_db_buffer etc, but reverted to defaults. No swapping,no partitioning (checked both!). Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Not a lot of exciting values in the variables/status.  `max_allowed_packet` is dangerously high at 1GB.  15 qps is low; various IO-related metrics echo that.  `Max_used_connections` = 40 implies you had a significant spike in activity; or something hung for quite some time.  Slow queries and table scans are high, but the system is not very busy.  Doing a purge and flush every 5 minutes; why?  I reviewed 120 computed Variables/Status/Expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Rick James ! `max_allowed_packet` is high because we used to have (large!) BLOBs in our tables. I rearranged this to be stored in S3 buckets instead, so I could absolutely tune this down. `max_used_connections` - well, this value is tied to BoneCP in a (for me) not entirely obvious way. So when our application is working, this is between 5-15 connections, when both environments are connected to the RDS instance this adds up. Finally, when I relaunch/update an EC2 instance, this could be 3 instances at one time, which would explain the ~40. (These are my assumptions!)

Comment: OK -- keep `max_allowed_packet` high, but make room for it by decreasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  You do _not_ want to swap; that would be terrible for performance.  Perhaps the 40 occurred when swapping.  Processes would start, but take for ever to finish.

Comment: I will look into finding a fitting `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. I don't think that RDS ever started swapping, at least the RDS monitoring shows absolutely no sign of it, also not when the slow-down occured again.

Answer (score 0):

There is one very important bit of information missing from your description:  The total allocated space for the database.  I/O for RDS is around 3x the allocated space, so for a 100GB allocation, you should get around 300 IOPS.  That allocated space also includes logs.

Since you don't really know what's going on, the first step should be to turn on detailed monitoring, which will give you more idea of what is happening on the instance.

Until you have additional stats gathered during a slowdown, you can try increasing the allocated space, which will increase the IOPS available.

Also, check the events for the db - are logs getting purged on a regular basis?  That might indicate that there's not enough space.

Finally, you can try going with PIOPS (provisioned IOPS) if you have an idea of what the application needs, though at this point it sounds like that would be a guess.

Comment: I have 100 GB storage allocated, but right now I set it to GENERAL PURPOSE rather than provisioned IOPS. Could this be an issue? The 100 GB are quite an overkill, I got rid of all legacy BLOB tables in our DB, so basically 2 GB storage would be more than enough for this DB. I agree that I need more data during a slowdown, I have set up NewRelic and try to gather as much as I can at this moment. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @konrad_pe:  You will get more information from RDS detailed stats than New Relic will be able to provide.

Comment: Okay, just enabled detailed monitoring on the RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your burst credit balance is (slowly) being depleted? finally, you end up with baseline performance, which may appear "too slow".

this would also explain why the upgrade to another instance type did help, as you then start with a full burst balance again.

i would suggest to increase the size of the volume, even if you don't need the extra space, [as the baseline performance grows linearly with volume size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html#EBSVolumeTypes_gp2).